# Pass previous url through url string query to text field on next page

Tags: jquery, string, url

I have read some posts on here but I am trying to achieve something that I cannot seem to find.

I want to grab the Page A url that the user is on, once the user clicks on a button, it grabs that current Page A url, places it in the url, then passes it to a text field on the next page (Page B).

I know how text fields work with string queries such as /?textfield="Thisisatext"

Then it would output as "Thisisatext" inside the text field.

I am trying to achieve this without using Javascript. or any other alternatives.

Comment: without javascript? how do you want to write it, a programming language need to be there, these things can't happen automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL is dynamic, it is not possible to pass it through url without Javascript. If it is a static url, you can simple do

```
<a href="urlToGo.com/olderurl="oldURL"/>
```

if it is dynamic url, then you need to get it with javascript, and mount the url to redirect to. Something like:

```
var url = document.URL;
var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId'); 
a.href = "newurl.com/" + "oldurl=""" + url + """
```

Comment: Thank you victor for this, sorry for the late message. So basically I have been trying to code my own and have been slowly learning.

This one still stumps me as it does require javascript so I guess I will need to create a separate file for the script.

The idea was that when a user was viewing an image on my photography site, they could click on a text that said "Add to favourites", it would then copy the current URL, open a new tab, pass that url to a text field, and the user can share it, as all the other images that they have "Added" will add the url to this field.